# Opening and closing panels

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I'm making an elevator, I've got the movement functions down but now I need to make them open and close. I've tried a few things but can't seem to get it to work.

Code for buttons

```
private void CP_GFButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (LDoor.Location.Y < 350)
                while (Rdoor.Location.Y < 350)
                {
                    LDoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(LDoor.Location.X, LDoor.Location.Y + 1);  //Move Left Door DOWN
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                    Rdoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Rdoor.Location.X, Rdoor.Location.Y + 1); // Move Right door DOWN
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
        }

        private void CP_OneFbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        // Move both lift doors up
        {
            while (LDoor.Location.Y > 90)
                while (Level1.Location.Y > 90)
                    while (Rdoor.Location.Y > 90)
                    {
                        LDoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(LDoor.Location.X, LDoor.Location.Y - 4);  // Move Left door UP
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                        Rdoor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Rdoor.Location.X, Rdoor.Location.Y - 4); //Move Right door UP
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                        Level1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Level1.Location.X, Level1.Location.Y - 4); //Move Right door UP
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                    }
        }
```

Attempted code:

```
while (LDoor.Width > 5)
{
  LDoor.Width--;
  LDoor.Width--;
  LDoor.Location = new Point(LDoor.Left + 1, LDoor.Top);
}
```

image of lift:

[image]

Comment: What does "can't seem to get it to work" mean?

Comment: Based on your `while` loop, I'm guessing you want to play an animation of the doors opening and closing. Is this right?

Comment: If I press '1' then the doors both disappear the same way, don't move and then the window crashes.

Comment: Yes Charlie that's right

Comment: The first thing I notice is, each time through the loop, you're subtracting 1 from the width of `LDoor` twice. You are never modifying the width of `Rdoor`. Is Is that what you are intending?

Comment: The second thing I notice is, inside your `while` loop, you never do any calls to `Sleep()`. So you would never see the animation -- it would either go by too fast, or be done before the drawing system has chance to draw the doors.

Comment: I would add that calling `Sleep()` on the user input thread will make the whole program non-responsive. This looks like homework to me, and in some cases with homework, shortcuts such as this one are fine. But in a production application, you should never put your UI thread to sleep like this.

Comment: Right I see. I forgot to post the RDoor code. It's the same as LDoor just with the names changed. I screencap'd the image of what happens. It does this and then goes upwards (if you press 1)
http://i.imgur.com/Mxlghcl.png

Comment: any ideas? fiddled around with it and can't get it to work.

Comment: I've got it half way I think... It opens and then it moves, I want it to move and then open. :/